# Android getting resource drawables in library project

Tags: android, resources

I have a Android Library Project, and i want to use the drawable resources. How do i do this?

`Bitmap fr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.drawable.fr)` does not work, because i need to replace `null` with `Resources`, retrieved by `getResources()`. However, as my Library Project has or is no activity and thus no `getResources()` method, it seems I can't use the resources. Any workaround or solution for using resources without an activity? (I'd rather not hardcode a filepath though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can pass Context object to the function, you can use

```
context.getResources()
```

Comment: No can't do. The interface I have to use doesn't support it.